# Best practices to implement a secure CAPTCHA

Tags: penetration-test, captcha, secure-coding

What are the best practices to implement a secure CAPTCHA?

Also I want to know:
What is the best way to identify an insecure CAPTCHA?

Comment: These are 2 very, very different questions. As for your first, have you seen the documents online that specify how to do this?

Comment: no, can you share me good documentation please?

Comment: We require that you have done a little research before posting here. Please look up how other implementations work and then come back with specific questions about what you still need help with,

Comment: Ok I understand, sorry